# How to prevent addresses being automatically added to Address Book in the Mac OS X Mail.app?

Tags: macos, apple-mail, address-book

Is there any way to disable the feature where Mail.app on OS X 10.6 will automatically add addresses into the address book when replying to an email from someone not in your address book already?

I have looked through the settings and tried to find ways around this on Google but nothing has come up.

Comment: Mail doesn't add addresses to your address book - it only adds them to an address *history*. Is that what you mean ?

Answer (score 3):

Look under the Window menu for the "Previous Recipients". You can view and edit there.

Answer (score 0):

This really is a problem that exists. It occurs if you use a mail server with MS Exchange. The steps to resolve:

- Open System Preferences
- Open Internet Accounts
- Select your Exchange Account
- Turn Off Contacts for Exchange

You should now see those automatic generated contacts gone. For more information, check out [this thread](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6717909?start=0&tstart=0) in Apple’s discussion forum.

Killing the list on Window/Previous Recipients will also help, but it's probably not what you want. The auto-complete is practical.